# how do I read the output of parseJSON step in powerApp portals

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am using power automate to fetch data from a CosmosDB and as the last step in the flow I use parseJSON to get the JSON object, this works fine and I can see the output with the JSON object.

The issue is that when I try and call the flow from power apps portals using the following code I get an error about unexpected JSON end of file

```
<script>
  function loadBrandSettings(){

    console.log('JongelStart');
      
    const fetchPromise = fetch('https://URL',
    {
      method: 'POST'
    });

    fetchPromise.then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(brandSettings => {
      console.log(brandSettings);
    });

  }
</script>
```

How can I call the flow and access the output from parseJSON which is the last step in my flow?